Как определить, какое действительное причастие использовать (настоящее или прошедшее время)?
Сколько читаю книг, постоянно натыкаюсь на действительные причастия как настоящего времени, так и прошедшего времени в одинаковых предложениях. Например:

Сидевшая и слышавшая разговор женщина тоже ничего не могла разобрать.


Сидящая и слышащая разговор женщина тоже ничего не могла разобрать.

Или более конкретный пример:

Мужчина, сидевший на стуле, встал.


Мужчина, сидящий на стуле, встал.

Есть ли правило, которое описывает применение действительных причастий в таком вопросе?

Зависит от того, что было до или будет после этого, о каком моменте/контексте идёт речь. Можно и так и так написать. Хотя "сидевший" больше похоже на бывшего зека.

@Буратино Не, не так надо.  Я тут придумала способ проверки, но не знаю, рассказывать или нет. Ссылка у меня на мировое информационное пространство, там посоветовали... )  Не знаю, есть ли такое.

Мировое информационное пространство? Интригующе! Рассказывайте, Sharon, делитесь советами!

Это шутка... Просто пришла в голову мысль,.. Но пока интересно, что другие скажут.

@Буратино так разве второй пример не описывает контекст? Человек сидел, а затем встал. Вместо "сидевший" может быть любой глагол, конечно))

Не описывает, в этом проблема. А в первом примере, кстати говоря, не понятно, это одна женщина или разные. Так что есть проблемы стилистические. И может быть ещё: сидящая на стуле и слышавшая весь разговор - женщина тоже ничего... - наверное так нужно писать. Или: слышавшая весь разговор женщина, сидящая на стуле, тоже ничего...

Ну или второе: по среди комнаты лежал окровавленный труп. По красным следам на обивке можно было предположить, что тело принадлежало мужчине, сидевшему на стуле.  Меня смущает постановка одиночных причастий перед определяемым словом. Дело в том, что причастие может выполнять роль существительного, поэтому начинается конфликт, если причастие в странной форме и еще в самом начале предложения. Сразу оп и какое-то состояние, ни с того, ни с сего. Это требует дополнительного контекста.

Посреди комнаты лежал труп. Шерлок сказал: "Это мужчина, сидевший на этом стуле, он встал, попытался подняться, но упал, оставив кровавые следы.."

В общем, так.
Надо сделать проверку: заменить причастный оборот придаточным предложением. Заодно правим стилистику, а также из двух вариантов (оборот или придаточное) выбираем подходящий.
Сидевшая рядом и слышавшая разговор женщина тоже ничего не могла разобрать. — Женщина, которая сидела рядом и слышала разговор, тоже ничего не могла разобрать.
Мужчина, сидящий на стуле, встал. — Мужчина, который в тот момент сидел на стуле, встал.
Другими словами, надо проверить время глагола: действие вообще в прошлом или в текущий момент прошлого (Past Continuous). При необходимости добавить временное наречие.

честно говоря, не совсем уловил суть, но зачту как ответ))

Я имела в виду следующее.  Если в прошедшем времени используется действительное причастие настоящего времени, то это долно иметь определенный смысл: именно в тот текущий момент.  Если используется причастие прошедшего времени, то  значение текущего момента не подчеркивается (это время вообще). Но в этом предложении мне не понравился стиль: Сидевшая и слышавшая разговор женщина тоже ничего не могла разобрать. Без распространителя "рядом"  форма сидевшая не выражает нужный смысл.  А если добавить, то оборот в препозиции становится сложным для чтения, здесь придаточное лучше.

Но это мое мнение, может, кто думает иначе. Для  обоснованного грамматикой или правилами ответа нужно теорию читать)

Я думаю нужно так: Сидевшая и слышавшая разговор — женщина тоже ничего не могла разобрать.

А если бы она была стоявшая?  У вас актуализация оборота, и какая-то сомнительная)

@Sharon спасибо за развернутый ответ.

А если бы она была стоявшая? - норм, а если "стоявшая она была" - не норм.

Это я не знаю) Я только хочу сказать, что предложение надо редактировать (с учетом контекста).  Бех контеста  слово сидевшая семантически недостаточное.  Какое имеет значение, что она сидела? Главное, она сидела рядом и поэтому слышала.  И вот если сделать замену  придаточным, это хорошо видно: которая сидела и слышала, да?
